# Disable Airplay with allowsExternalPlayback but audio is still playing

Tags: ios, airplay

I've disabled Airplay with allowsExternalPlayback , the video on AVPlayer is finished but audio is still playing .
   Please, help me, I tried to find solution with the help of google but I am not able to solve this problem:(

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour as you can also use it to define what audio-output should be used e.G. bluetooth, headphones, speakers and so on...